# Presionar imagen en JavaScript y llenar input

Tags: javascript, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo una duda, como puedo llenar los inputs cuando le doy click a la imagen, quiero llenarlos con cualquier dato que yo le de desde javascripts, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, las preguntas genéricas no son bien recibidas. En general se responde a cualquier duda o problema concreto que pueda surgir. Por otro lado siempre podrás acudir al `onclick` en la etiqueta `img` para llenar los inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes colocarle [Atributos data-](https://johnresig.com/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) a la imágen, y usar la función `.attr()` de Jquery para obtener esos datos y rellenarlos en el input.

```js
$('img').on('click', function(){
  $('#name').val($(this).attr('data-name'))
  $('#lastname').val($(this).attr('data-lastname'))
});
```

```css
.form{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 200px;
}

input{
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img data-name="Leonardo" data-lastname="DiCaprio" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/">

<div class="form">
<label for="name">Nombre</label>
<input id="name" class="name">
<label for="lastname">Apellido</label>
<input id="lastname" class="lastname">
</div>
```